# How can I show markers text when I click on any marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am creating a google maps page. I am dynamically adding markers through a loop. I want to display when I click on any marker. How can I achieve that? This is my loop.

```
if(data.STATUS == STATUS.SUCCESS){
    console.log("Markers Received");
    deleteMarkers();
    for(var i=0; i<data.DATA.length; i++){
        addMarker({lat: data.DATA[i].LATITUDE, lng: data.DATA[i].LONGITUDE},data.DATA[i].INCIDENT);
    }
}

function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
}

function addMarker(location,incident) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      title: incident
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}

function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}


function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
}

function clearMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
}

function showMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(map);
}
```

First of all I delete all the markers by this function. And then reset them. This call runs after every minute. I want to display the `incident` when ever I click on the marker. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, this helps.

```
var obj = {
    infoWindow: new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    marker: new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latLngObj,
            title: 'info name'
    })
};

google.maps.event.addListener(obj.marker, 'click', function() {
        obj.infoWindow.setContent("<div><b>" + obj.marker.title + "(" + distance + ")</b></div>");
        obj.infoWindow.open(map, obj.marker);
});
```

Comment: you can wrap event code in a function and modify that according to your use case. You can call that wrapper function from your addMarker function.(Mark answer if this helps).